# GetX State Management Flutter Not Changing the value

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-getx

I have non obs stateful class that return list of data

```
Class OvertimeDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  List<DataGetOvertime> listSelectedOT = [];
  bool isLongPressEnable = false;
  final String jenisPermit;
  Function() refreshState;
  OvertimeDetails(
      {Key key,
      this.jenisPermit,
      this.listSelectedOT,
      this.isLongPressEnable,
      this.refreshState})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListOvertimeState createState() => _ListOvertimeState();
}
```

then I call it to the parent class as Rx()

```
Rx<OvertimeDetails> listOvertimeDet;

void initState(){
 listOvertimeDet = OvertimeDetails(
        jenisPermit: widget.jenisPermit,
        isLongPressEnable: _isLongPressEnabled,
        listSelectedOT: []).obs;

}
```

I want to listen value change of selected list from OvertimeDetails by show it on app bar like this and it didn't work. But, it work properly when I press hot reload once after I selected the data from list, after that value listen correctly.

```
Obx(
          () => Text(listOvertimeDet.value.listSelectedOT == null
              ? "Multiple Approve"
              : "${listOvertimeDet.value.listSelectedOT.length} item selected"),
        )
```

Comment: Make it also reactive 'List<DataGetOvertime> listSelectedOT = [];' , hope it helps you :)

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya its already reactive  `RxList<DataGetOvertime> listSelectedOT = <DataGetOvertime>[].obs;` and its only work after I select one data from list then I do hot reloads (value change reactively).

Comment: Is it showing 'Multiple Approve' when the list is empty or '0 item selected'?

Comment: 0 item selected. after do some magic way. I found the problem sir. Now, its work perfectly. Thanks sir, you are inspiring me. ;)

Comment: I'm new to getX, but I think its to early to ask it here hahaha. But, At least I got some inspiration here after 2hour of dizziness xD

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. It would be good if you post your solution here for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // use this way
 // GetxController 

final employeeModelList = List<EmployeeModel>.empty(growable: true).obs;
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.